# WP Как задать шаблон по умолчанию для кастомного типа записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

После создания произвольного типа записи `bonuses`

```
////// BONUSES
///

add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_bonuses' ); // Использовать функцию только внутри хука init

function register_post_type_bonuses() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Бонусы',
        'singular_name' => 'Бонус',
        'add_new' => 'Добавить бонус',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новый бонус', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать бонус',
        'new_item' => 'Новый бонус',
        'all_items' => 'Все бонусы',
        'view_item' => 'Просмотр бонуса на сайте',
        'search_items' => 'Искать бонус',
        'not_found' =>  'Бонус не найдено.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет бонусов.',
        'menu_name' => 'Бонусы' // ссылка в меню в админке
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'bonus', 'casinoempt' ),
        'description' => __( 'Каталог Бонусов', 'casinoempt' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-money-alt', // иконка в меню
        'menu_position' => 20, // порядок в меню
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'bonuses'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields',),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,

    );
    register_post_type('bonuses', $args);
}
```

Ищу простой способ что бы все посты данного типа отображали информацию с определенного шаблона. Попробовал создать шаблон `single-bonuses.php`  `page-bonuses.php` но WP не выводит по умолчанию информацию с этих страниц. Только если добавить строку

```
/*
Template Name: Bonus
Template Post Type: bonuses

*/
```

Получается назначить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы по-умолчанию отображалось с указанных шаблонов страниц?

Comment: `single-bonuses.php` должен подключатся по умолчанию. Заголовки в этом случае не нужны и в админке он не выбирается.

Comment: Постоянные ссылки обновлены в админке?

Comment: И rewrite уберите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот несколько видоизменённый класс из одного моего рабочего плагина.

```
<?php
/**
 * CPT class file.
 *
 * @package my-plugin
 */

namespace MyPlugin\CPT;

/**
 * Class CPT
 */
class CPT {

    /**
     * Custom post type.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $custom_post_type = '';

    /**
     * Post taxonomy name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $post_tax = '';

    /**
     * Prefix in url.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $prefix = '';

    /**
     * Taxonomy label.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $tax_label = '';

    /**
     * Post label.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $post_label = '';

    /**
     * Projects constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->custom_post_type = 'bonuses';
        $this->post_tax         = 'bonus_type';
        $this->prefix           = 'bonuses';

        $this->tax_label  = __( 'Bonus Types', 'my-domain' );
        $this->post_label = __( 'Bonuses', 'my-domain' );
    }

    /**
     * Init class.
     */
    public function init(): void {
        add_filter( 'init', [ $this, 'register_cpt' ] );

        // Register activation hook to flush rewrite rules.
        register_activation_hook( WTEI_FILE, [ $this, 'activate_plugin' ] );

        // Register deactivation hook to flush rewrite rules.
        register_deactivation_hook( WTEI_FILE, [ $this, 'deactivate_plugin' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Create custom post type.
     */
    public function register_cpt(): void {
        register_taxonomy(
            $this->post_tax,
            [ $this->custom_post_type ],
            [
                'label'             => $this->tax_label,
                'public'            => true,
                'show_tagcloud'     => false,
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
                'hierarchical'      => false,
                'rewrite'           => [
                    'slug'         => $this->prefix,
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'with_front'   => false,
                ],
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
            ]
        );

        register_post_type(
            $this->custom_post_type,
            [
                'label'             => $this->post_label,
                'public'            => true,
                'capability_type'   => 'post',
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
                'hierarchical'      => false,
                'rewrite'           => [
                    'slug'       => $this->prefix . '/%' . $this->post_tax . '%',
                    'with_front' => false,
                    'feeds'      => false,
                ],
                'supports'          => [
                    'title',
                    'tags',
                    'excerpt',
                    'editor',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'page-attributes',
                ],
                'has_archive'       => false,
                'taxonomies'        => [ $this->post_tax ],
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-admin-site',
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Plugin activation hook.
     */
    public function activate_plugin(): void {
        // Register entities as they do not exist when activation hook is fired.
        // Otherwise flush_rewrite_rules() has nothing to do.
        $this->register_cpt();

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    /**
     * Plugin deactivation hook.
     */
    public function deactivate_plugin(): void {
        // Unregister entities here as they do already exist when deactivation hook is fired.
        // Otherwise flush_rewrite_rules() has nothing to do.

        // This also unregisters taxonomies.
        unregister_post_type( $this->custom_post_type );

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

Здесь важно то, надо регистрировать тип поста до `flush_rewrite_rules()`, иначе в хуке активации flush не сработает. То же самое по поводу хука деактивации.